# Cannot install RavenDb.Database 3.0.30000 via Nuget v3.2 in Visual Studio 2015 Community

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, nuget, ravendb

I want to try out NoSql Database, and based on some articles RavenDb is highly recommended for .Net. Now I cant even start because I cant install RavenDb.Database (v3.0.30000) on my Web project. Im not sure if the issue is in Nuget.

[image]

Im using the below tools if it matters.

- .Net 4.5.2
- ASP MVC 5 (empty template/no package added yet)
- Visual Studio 2015

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a nuget issue.
can you try this using the command line client?
Alternatively, just download the ravendb zip from our site

Comment: yeah for now Im using the downloaded zip and run the exe file. Then I just have to install the RavenDb.Client 3.0.30000

Comment: Do I have to buy license if I will be using it in Embedded Mode?

Comment: Yes, you do need to purchase a license.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.nuget.org/packages/RavenDB.Client/3.0.30000

find your version and download it from the menu on the left, hope this will be fixed